# CartoDB layer selector template

Tags: carto

I would like to create a HTML file where I have a layer selector dropdown list that would be able to display one layer from a specific CartoDB visualization (this visualization has several layers in it, but I just want to display one layer at a time on the API)

I have no development skills, so I am looking for a template to do this. Anyone here knows a template that I could use to do the job?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/layer_selector.html). It's a simple example using CartoDB.js that does what you want